# VBScript Append file only if file is not blank

Tags: csv, vbscript, append

I've compiled a script that adds a trailer to the end of a .csv file (to let the program reading it know that it's finished transmitting data.) Anyways, I'm trying to figure out how to only add this if the file that's referenced contains data.

```
dim filesys, filetxt 
Const ForReading = 1, ForWriting = 2, ForAppending = 8 
Set filesys = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") 
Set filetxt = filesys.OpenTextFile("C:\Test\Test.csv", ForAppending, True) 
filetxt.WriteLine(",,,,,,,,,,,," & vbCr)
filetxt.WriteLine(",,,,,,,,,,,," & vbCr)
filetxt.WriteLine(",,,,,,,,,,,," & vbCr)
filetxt.WriteLine(",,,,,,,,,,,," & vbCr)
filetxt.WriteLine(",,,,,,,,,,,," & vbCr)
filetxt.Close
```

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to check the size of the file:

```
strFile = "C:\file.txt"
SET objFSO = CREATEOBJECT("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
SET objFile = objFSO.GetFile(strFile)

If objFile.Size > 0 Then
   'do things here
Else
   'do nothing
End If
```

Comment: That worked, just for the sake of site history the first IF line is missing a "j" in objFile.size. Thanks!!!!